# how to load strings in plist into uitableview

Tags: iphone, arrays, string, uitableview, plist

Hey I have made up a plist file that has an array of strings init, I'm now trying to figure out a way to load it into my uitableview but am struggling to find a decent example of this.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the plist data into a data structure (probably an array using + (id)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
). Setup the UITableView's delegate to a class that has access to that array, tell the table view to reloadView.

Comment: This is how I'm calling stuff in the plist file... I guess I'm just stuck on passing it to the tableview... 

 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"searchItems" ofType:@"plist"];
 
 // Build the array from the plist  
 NSMutableArray *searchItemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

Comment: There are going to be lots of references on how to do that kind of thing on the web. Its not complicated, but its already been spelled out. Googling found this hit, for example, http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/

Comment: Yea, that link you sent me is okay but has alot of interface builder crap in it.. I ended up getting it to work, just checking over to see if the way I did it is tidy.. I used an example here : 
http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=85

Comment: good deal. yup, im sure there are lots of references out there, google is your friend.